# Validate the PDF file is digitally signed or not

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I got one document from the external system. I don't know in which signatureFieldName added inside the document.
Then how i will validate that this document is digitally signed or not.

I am using iText7 for digital signature.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If it did, please accept the answer (you accept it by clicking the checkmark at its upper left). If it didn't, please explains what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether there are any signed signature fields in a PDF by checking `SignatureUtil.getSignatureNames()` which according to its JavaDocs *Gets the field names that have signatures and are signed.*

```java
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(...);
SignatureUtil signUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDoc);
List<String> names = signUtil.getSignatureNames();
if (names.isEmpty()) {
    [... handle case of unsigned PDF ...]
} else {
    [... handle case of PDF signed at least once ...]
}
```